# JMX real-time monitoring application

Tags: monitoring, java, jmx

I'm looking for a (probably) desktop application to monitor applications through JMX in real-time. The application must provide the capability to design a dashboard with charts and gauges with values coming from several JMX queries. I must be able to set thresholds to some values and be alerted with sounds if the value goes beyond the threshold.

The application will be always running on a big monitor in our operation room.

Traditional monitoring application like Nagios, Hyperic and others does not fit well in my "real-time" requirement. They are also excelent at maintaining the history of monitoring or at alerts, but lack a good and fast GUI.

My budget is $200, but free and opensource are always preferred. I do have some time to customize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of [JMXTrans](https://github.com/lookfirst/jmxtrans) and [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/). JMXTrans will periodically get the values of your JMX counters and then store them in Graphite.  Graphite can then graph them for you.

As others have mentioned there are some SAAS solutions as well:

- https://metrics.librato.com/
- http://www.datadoghq.com

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of JMX tools that can do what you want.

Do you have a budget in mind? Does it have to be free? Cheap? Enterprise? ITRS/BMC/HPOV are all larger, expensive solutions.

How much effort are you going to be putting in to customise it? Nagios/Zenoss/etc are free, but easily extensible.

Comment: Oh and Hyperic is both OpenSource and Enterprise available, and targeted at JMX monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

Zenoss Core has a ZenPack for monitoring JMX: http://community.zenoss.org/docs/DOC-4027  Open Source and free, the JMX ZenPack is used by lots of users and customers on some really big apps.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `Java Mission Control` which is part of recent JDK7 releases and all JDK8 releases. The binary is called `jmc` on Linux and `jmc.exe` on Windows and it is located in `$JAVA_HOME/bin/`.

The default sample rate is 1 second, but it is configurable for each MBean attribute.

Besides monitoring the items exposed by JMX you can run a profiler called `Java Flight Recorder`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll build a list of packages I find:

- http://www.sl.com/solutions/jmxusers.shtml
- ...

Answer (score 0):

Try MC4J, is free too

http://mc4j.org/confluence/display/mc4j/Home

Comment: I tried, but I may be stupid because I didn't manage to run it. I think the installation on my Win2008 box failed somehow and I cannot find a way to run it...

Answer (score -1):

Try the best solution in monitoring software: [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/).

There are several JMX plugins on the net: [nagios jmx](http://www.lmgtfy.com/?q=nagios+jmx).